# R: extracting numbers from levels in a factor (where the levels contain characters and numbers)

Tags: r

I have a dataset with ppts' ages in one column (options: 17-22). If a ppt was older than 22, they have a value of 8, and in the next column they will have entered a comment with their age.

[For example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uD270.png)

I have tried to write a for loop with an if statement:

```
for(i in 1:nrows(df){
if(df$Age[i] == 8){
#extract the numerical value in $Age.comment[i] and replace
#df$Age[i] with this value
}
}
```

since the $Age.comment is a factor ($Age is numerical), and the levels contain numbers and characters, I am stumped as to how to do this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!! Thank you!

Comment: This has little to do with factors. How do you extract the numbers from `"I am 25 yrs old"` in general? Answer that and use it for your application.

Answer (score 1):

This should get you close.

```
df <- data.frame(Age = 1:8, Age.comment = paste(16:23, LETTERS[1:8]))
df
#   Age Age.comment
# 1   1        16 A
# 2   2        17 B
# 3   3        18 C
# 4   4        19 D
# 5   5        20 E
# 6   6        21 F
# 7   7        22 G
# 8   8        23 H

ifelse(df$Age == 8, gsub("\\D", "", df$Age.comment), df$Age)
#[1] "1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "23"
```

The regular expression `"\\D"` says "match all non-numerical characters". We replace these with blanks leaving the numbers only.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `parse_number` from `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, New := Age][Age==8, New := parse_number(Age.comment)]
df$New
#[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7 23
```